# JTable refresh issue

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable, tablemodel

I'm having a hard time with a `JTable` data refreshing.

I'm implementing my own `TableModel`, extending from `javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel`, with a method that receives an `java.util.ArrayList<>` and process it to build an `Object[][]` from where the table data is read.

The logic is as following:

I'm implementing a JList with some record keys, when the user selects one, a method is fired that picks up the key and queries a MySQL database to fetch records related with that key. The final result is an ArrayList<> that I passed to the TableModel to construct the data and then set it to my table.

It works normally but after a few hits, it stops displaying the table data, and after a little time, it starts working again. I'm not sure if I'm having problem refreshing the table or the entire GUI.

This is a excerpt of the code:

Method for build the data of the table:

```
public void createTableData(java.util.ArrayList<Lote> alLote) {
    //Lote is an entity class modeling the database table.
    TABLE_DATA = new Object[alLote.size()][TABLE_COLUMNS.length];
    //TABLE_DATA is an Object array, TABLE_COLUMNS is a String[] containing the names of the columns.
    int i = 0;
    for (Lote element : alLote) {
        int j = 0;
        TABLE_DATA[i][j++] = element.getFirstColumnValue();
        //and so son
        i++;
    }
    super.fireTableDataChanged();
}
```

When launching the GUI, it starts with an empty ArrayList<>:

```
LoteTableModel ltm = new LoteTableModel();
arrayList = new ArrayList<Lote>();
ltm.createTableData(arrayList);
myTable = new JTable();
myTable.setModel(ltm);
scrollPane = new JScrollPane(myTable);
```

I'm using DesignGridLayout btw, a RowGroup which hides when the table has no records and shows when it has results, and a JScrollPane as table container.

```
dgl = new DesignGridLayout(panel);
dgl.row().center().group(group).add(scrollPaneContainingTable).fill();
centerPanel.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
getContentPane().add(centerPanel);
centerPanel.setVisible(true);
```

Then, everytime the user selects an item from a JList, I query the database and fetch records related to the selected value:

```
public void listSelectionChanged() {
    bloque = alBloque.get(listBloque.getSelectedIndex());
    //bloque is another entity, alBloque is an ArrayList<Bloque> from which the JList (named listBloque) ListModel is constructed.
    try {
        //database query here, omitted
        if (result.getStatus() == SUCCESS) {
            //the query returned a populated ArrayList<Lote>
            alLote = result.getArray();
            ((LoteTableModel) myTable.getModel()).createTableData(alLote);
            myTable.revalidate();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

As I stated before, it works fine a couple of times, clicking the values on the list displays their related records on the table, but then after clicking several ones, it stops displaying data at all. Leaving it for a moment and then clicking on some value again, will display the correct data again, so as I told before, I'm not sure if is more like a GUI refreshing issue.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't swallow exceptions.

Comment: Actually it was for shortening purposes when making the question. I do a multicatch for `java.io.IOException` and `ClassNotFoundException`.

Comment: try painting the content pane. That refreshes the GUI.

Comment: I don't know why your translating the ArrayList to a Object[][], seems to me you have all the data you need for the table model stored in the ArrayList.

Comment: @shrigurunayak if the model is correctly registered with the table and the table is add to a viewable component, then the fireTableStructureChanaged method will require the table to repaint it self (as well as rebuild its column model and reset its renderers and editors)

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind, from the snippet, is to make sure you are apply the table values to the model from within in the context of the EDT

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks. That was the issue I faced when I created a desktop app using `swings`. Just shared my experience.

Comment: just a couple of comments: a) with a well-behaved model there's *never* a need to _revalidate_ or the other way round: if revalidate seems to "fix" an update issue, something wrong with your model b) you most probably only want to update the data _once_ after the selection change is final, to ensure that check the getValueIsAdjusting property of the event

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments. I will check on @MadProgrammer suggestion to ensure I'm withing the EDT context.

@kleopatra, actually, the `listSelectionListener` event only fires the `valueChanged` behavior when `getValueIsAdjusting` is false.

Comment: I have checked on the code, the change is being made within the EDT. Is kinda weird indeed. I will keep on looking. Thanks a lot, guys.

Comment: @Noe Make your most recent edit concerning a solution to this question by posting it below, and then mark it as  an "accepted" answer by clicking the checkmark.  Good job on finding the solution!

Comment: @HyperAnthony, thank you, I have do so :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the issue, and as I thought, it was a GUI issue, not of refreshing, but of misuse of the Layout package :)

As I stated, I'm using `DesignGridLayout`, it has the benefit of creating a group of rows, called `RowGroup` and hide it or show it according to the GUI convenience/need.

I placed the table in a `RowGroup` and call the `show()` method when there were results on the database, and the table was loaded with these results,thus displaying it; I called the `hide()` method when no results were found and therefore, the table will be empty, so I hide it.

The point is that calling the `hide()` method is cumulative... If I called the method 3 times, I would need to call the show() method 3 times too in order to show it, so, if I choose 3 consecutive rows in my `JList` with empty result sets for the table, I will be calling the `hide()` method 3 times, so when I choose a row that indeed had results for the table, I will be calling the `show()` method just once, so the table never displayed as expected until 3 attempts at selecting rows with results for the table.

I have put a control field which forces the app to call the `hide()` method just once, because sadly, the `DesignGridLayout` package doesn't include an `isHide()` method to test if `hide()` has been called.

Thank you very much for your support. My mystery question is now solved.

Comment: DesignGridLayout RowGroup cannot have an `isHidden()` API because it doesn't have a state on its own. It just delegates `show()` and `hide()` to the rows that belong to it.

Comment: However, what should be possible is to add a new API in rows and RowGroup, like `forceShow()` that would show the row (or all rows in the group) even if `hide()` had been called many times before.

Comment: @jfpoilpret, that would be great indeed. I understand the reason we cannot have a test method, but having one that forces the rows to show is useful too. Thanks for your comment.